# How to clear local storage in Cypress test?

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, local-storage, cypress

At the beginning of my Cypress test scenario, I need to click the **Agree and Proceed** button on the below IFrame:

[image]

The problem is that after clicking this button during my first test run, the user's consent is stored in the local storage as you can see here:

[image: storage]

If I re-run my test again, it will fail because the local storage is storing the user's consent, so the IFrame asking for consent won't appear.

If I manually clear the `truste.consent.willistowerswatson.com` key from local storage and re-run my test, it will pass.

I need to somehow automatically clear this value.

I tried to specify the `key` value with the below code, but it isn't clearing the value:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    cy.clearLocalStorage('truste.consent.willistowerswatson.com')
})

it('First test', () => {
    cy.visit('http://www.willistowerswatson.com/ICT');
    cy.iframe('[id^=pop-frame]').find('.call').should('have.text', 'Agree and Proceed').click()
})
```

Can someone explain how I can clear this value from local storage, so my test can re-run without any issue?

Answer (score 2):

You can remove this specific key by running:

```
localStorage.removeItem(‘truste.consent.willistowerswatson.com‘);
```

Alternatively, if desired, you can delete the entire localStorage as follows:

```
localStorage.clear();
```

You also find more info in the MDN Web Docs here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage